# Is it possible to make an interface extendable without it being implementable?

Tags: java, interface, package, visibility, extends

To make what I think is a reasonable analogy, suppose I have a "drink" interface. I can fill it, dump it, and maybe do some other things. I need to know how many people are drinking this drink before I put the straws in it. So naturally this leads to a "OneStrawDrink" interface with a drinkFromStraw() method and a "TwoStrawDrink" interface with drinkFromLeftStraw() and drinkFromRightStraw() methods. I would prefer that both of these interfaces extend the drink interface in the event that I ever need to change what a drink does, but I don't want anyone to be able to implement the "drink" interface because it is undrinkable without knowing how many straws to put in. oneStrawDrink and twoStrawDrink would still have to be recognized as drinks outside of my package, so leaving the drink interface package-private is not an option. is it possible to make the drink interface unimplementable? Or will I have to restructure this to get the desired functionality?

Comment: Sounds like you should restructure something. Your interfaces are either [too large](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) or actually should not [inherit from each other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) or something similar.

Comment: I thought that extending from the dink interface would make it more minimal. Is copying all of the methods of drink into the other interfaces and leaving drink as an empty interface ever advisable?

Comment: Things that are common to all drinks should be in one interface. Things that are common for all two straw things should be in one. Two straw must not necessarily extend Drink. A TwoStrawDrink could implement Drink and TwoStraw for example. Or TwoStrawDrink could implement Drink and have a member that implements TwoStraw.